# ARKit with multiple users

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, ios11, arkit, multiplayer

What is the best way, if any, to use Apple's new ARKit with multiple users/devices?

It seems that each devices gets its own scene understanding individually. My best guess so far is to use raw features points positions and try to match them across devices to glue together the different points of views since ARKit doesn't offer any absolute referential reference.

===Edit1, Things I've tried===

1) Feature points

I've played around and with the exposed raw features points and I'm now convinced that in their current state they are a dead end:

- they are not raw feature points, they only expose positions but none of the attributes typically found in tracked feature points
- their instantiation doesn't carry over from frame to frame, nor are the positions exactly the same
- it often happens that reported feature points change by a lot when the camera input is almost not changing, with either a lot appearing or disappearing.

So overall I think it's unreasonable to try to use them in some meaningful way, not being able to make any kind of good point matching within one device, let alone several.
Alternative would to implement my own feature point detection and matching, but that'd be more replacing ARKit than leveraging it.

2) QR code

As @Rickster suggested, I've also tried identifying an easily identifiable object like a QR code and getting the relative referential change from that fixed point (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579839/ios-revert-camera-projection)) It's a bit difficult and implied me using some openCV to estimate camera pose. But more importantly very limiting

Comment: Any chance you could send the device's compass data and/or orientation data to a server to allow for translation to another device's coordinate system?

Comment: That's possible. Multiplayer AR exp will probably involve some server backed synchronization anyway. But that'd not give me the precise translation difference between the two devices. If the mapping could be done solely with compass, accelerometer and GPS, there'd be no need for complex SLAM technology like what Apple is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, after releasing ARKit 2.0 at WWDC 2018, it's possible to make games for 2....6 users.

For this, you need to use `ARWorldMap` class. By saving `world maps` and using them to start new sessions, your iOS application can now add new Augmented Reality capabilities: multiuser and persistent AR experiences.

**AR Multiuser experiences**. Now you may create a shared frame of a reference by sending archived `ARWorldMap` objects to a nearby iPhone or iPad. With several devices simultaneously tracking the same `world map`, you may build an experience where all users (up to 6) can share and see the same virtual 3D content (use Pixar's `USDZ` file format for 3D in Xcode 10+ and iOS 12+).

```
session.getCurrentWorldMap { worldMap, error in 
    guard let worldMap = worldMap else {
        showAlert(error)
        return
    }
}

let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.initialWorldMap = worldMap
session.run(configuration)
```

**AR Persistent experiences**. If you save a `world map` and then your iOS application becomes inactive, you can easily restore it in the next launch of app and in the same physical environment. You can use `ARAnchors` from the resumed `world map` to place the same virtual 3D content (in USDZ or DAE format) at the same positions from the previous saved session.

Comment: Just a note that you can attach ordinary scenekit content to the anchors - and save/retrieve this along with the map (doesn't necessarily have to be USDZ). Our startup has an SDK that can dynamically load the correct map at the correct time as well - jordan@jordancampbell.org if anyone is interested.

Comment: totally agree))

Answer (score 10):

As some newer answers have added, multiuser AR is a headline feature of ARKit 2 (aka ARKit on iOS 12). [The WWDC18 talk on ARKit 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/602/) has a nice overview, and Apple has two developer sample code projects to help you get started: a [basic example](https://docs.devpubs.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_a_multiuser_ar_experience) that just gets 2+ devices into a shared experience, and [SwiftShot](https://docs.devpubs.apple.com/documentation/arkit/swiftshot_creating_a_game_for_augmented_reality), a real multiplayer game built for AR.

The major points:

1. [`ARWorldMap`](https://docs.devpubs.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldmap) wraps up everything ARKit knows about the local environment into a serializable object, so you can save it for later or send it to another device. In the latter case, "relocalizing" to a world map saved by another device in the same local environment gives both devices the same frame of reference (world coordinate system).
2. Use the networking technology of your choice to send the `ARWorldMap` between devices: AirDrop, cloud shares, <strike>carrier pigeon</strike>, etc all work, but Apple's [Multipeer Connectivity framework](https://docs.devpubs.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity) is one good, easy, and secure option, so it's what Apple uses in their example projects.
3. All of this gives you only the *basis* for creating a shared experience — multiple copies on your app on multiple devices all using a world coordinate system that lines up with the same real-world environment. That's all you need to get multiple users experiencing the same *static* AR content, but if you want them to *interact* in AR, you'll need to use your favorite networking technology some more.

   Apple's [basic multiuser AR demo](https://docs.devpubs.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_a_multiuser_ar_experience) shows encoding an `ARAnchor`
   and sending it to peers, so that one user can tap to place a 3D
   model in the world and all others can see it. The [SwiftShot game example](https://docs.devpubs.apple.com/documentation/arkit/swiftshot_creating_a_game_for_augmented_reality) builds a whole networking protocol so that all users get the same gameplay actions (like firing slingshots at each other) and synchronized physics results (like blocks falling down after being struck). Both use [Multipeer Connectivity](https://docs.devpubs.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity).

<sub>(BTW, the second and third points above are where you get the "2 to 6" figure from [@andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50745695/957768) — there's no limit on the ARKit side, because ARKit has no idea how many people may have received the world map you saved. However, Multipeer Connectivity has an 8 peer limit. And whatever game / app / experience you build on top of this may have latency / performance scaling issues as you add more peers, but that depends on your technology and design.)</sub>

Original answer below for historical interest...

---

This seems to be an area of active research in the iOS developer community — I met several teams trying to figure it out at WWDC last week, and nobody had even begun to crack it yet. So I'm not sure there's a "best way" yet, if even a feasible way at all.

Feature points are positioned relative to the session, and aren't individually identified, so I'd imagine correlating them between multiple users would be tricky.

The session alignment mode [`gravityAndHeading`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration.worldalignment/2873776-gravityandheading) might prove helpful: that fixes all the *directions* to a (presumed/estimated to be) absolute reference frame, but *positions* are still relative to where the device was when the session started. If you could find a way to relate that position to something absolute — a lat/long, or an iBeacon maybe — and do so reliably, with enough precision... Well, then you'd not only have a reference frame that could be shared by multiple users, you'd also have the main ingredients for location based AR. (You know, like a floating virtual arrow that says turn *right there* to get to Gate A113 at the airport, or whatever.)

Another avenue I've heard discussed is image analysis. If you could place some real markers — easily machine recognizable things like QR codes — in view of multiple users, you could maybe use some form of object recognition or tracking (a ML model, perhaps?) to precisely identify the markers' positions and orientations relative to each user, and work back from there to calculate a shared frame of reference. Dunno how feasible that might be. (But if you go that route, or similar, note that [ARKit exposes a pixel buffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867984-capturedimage) for each captured camera frame.)

Good luck!

Comment: `gravityAndHeading` is a good call. I'll try that using that. I can't rely on QR codes or beacons, but I might be able to identify some other images. I'll look at object recognition with the new ML features in iOS 11. I'm thinking of looking at things on walls first because they present just one face, but that might not be very concluent.

Comment: Feature points are too messy to be reliable: they get added and removed in a way that is hard to understand, and they don't have more information than their estimated 3D positioning so they are really hard to match accros frames, not mentioning across devices. I've started to work on the QR code approach as a first step into this but I'm getting stuck on the math.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579839/ios-revert-camera-projection

Comment: `gravityAndHeading` is actually very buggy. The -z axis does not correspond with north at all, and can be off by 150 degrees (so far in my tests).

Answer (score 1):

Not bulletproof answers more like workarounds but maybe you'll find these helpful. 
All assume the players are in the same place.

1. **DIY** ARKit sets up it's world coordinate system quickly after the AR session has been started. So if you can have all players, one after another, put and align their devices to the same physical location and let them start the session there, there you go. Imagine the inside edges of an L square ruler fixed to whatever available. Or any flat surface with a hole: hold phone agains surface looking through the hole with camera, (re)init session.
2. **Medium** Save the player aligning phone manually, instead detect a real world marker with image analysis just like @Rickster described.
3. **Involved** Train an Core ML model to recognize iPhones and iPads and their camera location. Like it's done with human face and eyes. Aggregate data on a server, then turn off ML to save power. Note: make sure your model is cover-proof. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of updating my game controller framework (https://github.com/robreuss/VirtualGameController) to support a shared controller capability, so all devices would receive input from the control elements on the screens of all devices.  The purpose of this enhancement is to support ARKit-based multiplayer functionality.  I'm assuming developers will use the first approach mentioned by diviaki, where the general positioning of the virtual space is defined by starting the session on each device from a common point in physical space, a shared reference, and specifically I have in mind being on opposite sides of a table.  All the devices would launch the game at the same time and utilize a common coordinate space relative to physical size, and using the inputs from all the controllers, the game would remain theoretically in sync on all devices.  Still testing.  The obvious potential problem is latency or disruption in the network and the sync falls apart, and it would be difficult to recover except by restarting the game. The approach and framework may work for some types of games fairly well - for example, straightforward arcade-style games, but certainly not for many others - for example, any game with significant randomness that cannot be coordinated across devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hugely difficult problem - the most prominent startup that is working on it is [6D.ai](http://6D.ai).

"Multiplayer AR" is the same problem as persistent SLAM, where you need to position yourself in a map that you may not have built yourself. It is the problem that most self driving car companies are actively working on.