# How to delegate ARSession and AVCaptureSession at the same time?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ios11, arkit

I've seen people running ARKit with `ARSCNView`, and they're able to fetch said a QR code rectangle in the camera and render something at the position somehow related to the place QR code resided in the space. I thought they did it by delegating `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`, so I went ahead and attempt to achieve the following logic:

1. Running `ARSCNViewDelegate`, `ARSessionDelegate` and `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` at the same time.
2. Wire up an `ARSCNView`, delegate the view and its session to self.
3. Wire up an `AVCaptureSession`, delegate it to self, and start the session.
4. Start the `ARSCNView` session, since the official example did this in `viewWillAppear()`, I did the same thing.

The application did run without any error, but I could only get a few callbacks from `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`, like 3 to 5, and then it would never be called again like the delegate of `ARSession` seized its authority, was I implementing the wrong approach or you just can't delegate `ARSession` and `AVCaptureSession` at the same time?

Comment: Did you know what they use to render something at the 3D position of the QRCode ?

Comment: If you're able to get the metadata of the camera frame, you can transfer the rect of QRCode to 3D coordinate and do your render stuff.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do a week ago, but I didn't succeed...I'm trying to understand you can transfer the rect of QRCode knowing its position on screen to 3D coordinate.Do you need a particular framework to do that?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579839/ios-revert-camera-projection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did exactly what you describe and have the same problems. It seems that ARKit relies upon the `AVCapture` system, and doesn't support using more than one capture device at a time. I found two solutions.

1. Start an `ARSession`, and implement the function `session(_:didUpdate:)` of `ARSessionDelegate`. Every time you capture an `ARFrame` search for a QR code in the image of the frame. ([code](https://github.com/donMichaelL/qrCode-Arkit))

   ```
   func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
       let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage)
       let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: nil, options: nil)
       let features = detector!.features(in: image)

       for feature in features as! [CIQRCodeFeature] {
           if !discoveredQRCodes.contains(feature.messageString!) {
               discoveredQRCodes.append(feature.messageString!)
               let url = URL(string: feature.messageString!)
               let position = SCNVector3(frame.camera.transform.columns.3.x,
                                         frame.camera.transform.columns.3.y,
                                         frame.camera.transform.columns.3.z)
           }
        }
   }
   ```
2. Start an `AVCaptureSession`, when you identify and decode your QR code stop it and start an `ARSession`. (not recommended)