# ARKit share worldmap session file

Tags: session, augmented-reality, arkit

Is it possible to share the session worldmap file to other devices in order to have an already mapped place before entering, for example, a museum?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44529350/10882208)

Or you can watch Apple’s WWDC videos about world map sharing and multiplayer games

Comment: Yes but my objective is not for this to be multiplayer or online experience but rather a simple offline experience with an already mapped room.

Comment: @DavidFilipe: By the help of the ARCore and Firebase, you can persist the world map and can restore it later. Even world map persist from Android can be restored.